# select all rows with a question mark

Tags: postgresql

I've been asked to check an entire database for all records with a question mark (?). I assume I can only do this on a table basis, is there any short cut or do I have to run

`SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [field] LIKE '%?%'`

for each column?

Comment: Please disambiguate *"records with a question mark (?)"*, define your desired return type, and always disclose your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Your objective is slightly ambiguous:

> all records with a question mark (?)

Columns that are not [character data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) may or may not contain a question mark, depending on their text *representation*.

Also, this could mean to filter for any columns *equaling* '?' or just *containing* '?'.

A dead simple solution for the *"containing"* interpretation (and ignoring my first concern - which seems safe enough for '?') is to **cast the whole row** to `text` - generating the default text representation of everything, plus delimiters and decorators - none of which include the question mark (`?`) per default:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl t WHERE t::text LIKE '%?%';
```

You would run this for every (relevant!) table in the DB. (You'll want to exclude system tables at least.) I added an example implementation to the related question on SO:

- [How to search a specific value in all tables (PostgreSQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350088/how-to-search-a-specific-value-in-all-tables-postgresql/50024712#50024712)

Related answer on SE Code Review:

- [SQL: Search for a keyword in several columns of a table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/sql-search-for-a-keyword-in-several-columns-of-a-table/7231#7231)